# how to map different rows in join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using this query, but this is not giving expected result. I want the result to have unique mapped_id. However, it always returns the 1st match. I tried with DISTINCT also, but to no avail.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Item A
INNER JOIN Collection B ON A.item_id=B.item_id
GROUP BY
    A.item_id,
    B.id,
    B.collection_id
```

Here are my tables:

Collection

```
id      | collection_id | item_id
a           1               100
b           1               200
c           1               200
```

Item

```
item_id | mapped_id
100         abc 
200         def
200         ghi
```

This is the output with the above query:

```
collection_id | item_id | mapped_id
1               100         abc
1               200         def
1               200         def
```

However, my expected result is:

```
collection_id | item_id | mapped_id
1               100         abc
1               200         def
1               200         ghi
```

Comment: why do you need a group by?  Group by is used when you have aggregation.  I see no aggregation here.

Comment: @xQbert not exactly, but its a part of bigger schema where I needed to group result set.

Answer (score 3):

SQLlite must implement group by extensions similar to that of mySQL.. otherwise you should be getting  an error about group by without an aggregate.

In My Opinion you don't need a group by here.  You just need distinct on the join because 200 from collection maps to ***TWO*** different 200s from items.  This would result in 4 records and by using distinct you get the 2 different ones.  Or you need to also group by A.mapped_ID

Fundamentally when you join on item_Id you get a result similar too.

```
200 def
200 def
200 ghi
200 ghi
```

By adding distinct you should only get 1 of each.  This could also be accomplished by grouping by mapped_ID as well.

***The issue here is that your key value in item on which you're joining represents 2 different records.***  Thus the key is incomplete (or doesn't follow normal form) in a relational design.  So database design is off, data is off, or your joining on an incomplete key.  (what's the unique index for item?)  If it's just item_ID then explain how the table has 2 200s!  if there is no unique key or primarykey, then you have a design flaw.  If there is a unique index/primary key it must be a composite key on multiple columns, in which case your missing criteria on your join.

```
SELECT Distinct B.collectioN_ID, B.item_Id, A.mapped_ID
FROM Item A
INNER JOIN Collection B ON A.item_id=B.item_id
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Item A
INNER JOIN Collection B ON A.item_id=B.item_id
GROUP BY
    A.item_id,
    B.id,
    B.collection_id,
    A.Mapped_ID  -- since you want distinct ones.  this should get rid of the 1 duplicate for each 200 in your example.
```

Comment: it's very old to revisit though I vaguely recall the issue. Collection table was not normalized. bcz item_id could be actual or a temp. As soon as backend mapped temp id with actual ones, we used to update that in collection table. Now, multiple temp ids could map to one actual id, thus leaving duplicates & since Keys should not be updated, making it ineligible for forming composite key. I did not have a solution back then so I left the table without key only to realize how f..ed up it was. I want to know, what will be better approach to provide key to the collection table in such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, this is this MySQL?

If you want to have all unique values of `mapped_id`, I suggest you group by `mapped_id`.
How about this:

```
SELECT     B.collection_id, A.item_id, A.mapped_id
FROM       Item       A
INNER JOIN Collection B  ON (A.item_id=B.item_id)
GROUP BY   B.collection_id, A.item_id, A.mapped_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT collection_id, A.item_id, mapped_id
FROM
    Item A
INNER JOIN Collection B ON A.item_id=B.item_id
GROUP BY
    A.item_id,
    B.collection_id,
    mapped_id
```